Nodemon not working when using script but works when I use it manually
I had recently been working on project
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  }

Following are my script when I tried to run npm run dev it gave me the following error:

'Projects\Backend\Chai\chaiAurBackend\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Web Devlopment\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.6.1

And ya, Me running it manually works! I tried running the same command and it worked. I don't get what is this specefic problem me running it with npm cause not me running it manually
Also, I noticed one more thing:
My working dir is this:  `
E:\Web Devlopment\Web Devlopment & Projects\Backend\Chai\chaiAurBackendAnd error dir is this:E:\Web Devlopment\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js`
Is there something to do with that?
I tried running the same command in different ways such as
npx nodemon index.js npx nodemon src/index.js nodemon . npx nodemon .
But neither of them work and i get the same error.

It looks like you installed nodemon globally on your system, which should not be an issue in general, but might cause an issue in your specific case.
Try installing nodemon as a development dependency in your project locally by running npm install --save-dev nodemon.
Then your dev script should work just fine.

I have tried that even that dosen't work it's something related to dir and path..
